# v-options keeps same options [VUE]

Tags: javascript, debugging, vuejs2

I'm trying to implement a select box while using `Vue`.

In my template I have the following piece of code:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <v-select v-model="search">
        <v-option v-for="option in Options" :value="option">{{ option }}</v-option>
    </v-select>
</div>
```

the import:

```
 import { select, option } from 'vue-strap/dist/vue-strap';
```

This is a generic component which is being used in different pages on the web (the move to another path does not require to refresh the page).

If I move between those pages, it will keep the old options. In order to understand the issue, please consider the following example:

Page A has the following list of options: `[dog,cat]`

Page B has the following list of options: `[bird,dog]`

- If I open page A it will show: `[dog,cat]`.
- If i'll move to page B, it will show `[dog,dog,cat,bird]`.
- If i'll move to page A again, it will show `[dog,dog,cat,bird,dog,cat]`.

I tried to initialize the `options` in `watch` everytime the `$route` changes, but it didn't help.

Any suggestion on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Maybe create a codepen to distill it down a bit?

Comment: it would help if you provide more code, maybe you're changing Options array when you change pages